# ionic large http get response causing shut down the application

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am developing a `cordova` application with `ionic 2`.I request the API, the thing causing the problem is response size of the API.The size of response is 9,3MB.
After I call the `requestCall()` function, it is not print my output to the console like codes below.and the value of `this.case` never happen `"success"`.After some time(0-1 min after call) the application is closing.Not giving any error or something,it is simply closing.Btw 
in `chrome://inspect/#devices` I can see the API request is working and getting the datas.The screenshot of request is
[image: here]

By the way, if I reduce the data size to 6MB everything is working fine.
Could you please help me to solve this problem?

This is my API service,I request getAll() function from my page.

```
 @Injectable()
export class ApiService {

constructor(private http: Http) { 
  } 

 getAll(){
     return this.http.get(`${API_URL+'/List?accId='+ ACC_ID+'&appCode='+APP_CODE}`)
            .map((res:Response)=>{ 
              return res.json();
            })
            .catch((error:any)=>Observable.throw(error)||'server error');
    }

}
```

Within this page, I call requestServer function by clicking the button.

```
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api/api-service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
 case:any="";

  constructor(private apiService:ApiService) {
   }
 requestServer(){
    this.case="pending";
      this.apiService. getAll().subscribe(res=>{
          console.log("viiiii");
          this.case="success";

         },error=>{
      console.log("err");
      console.log(error);
    });
    }
```

Comment: try console.log error in your subscribe error function and remote debug

Comment: I updated the code and I am doing remote debug, but still not printing any error @SurajRao

Comment: Smells a bit like an OutOfMemory exception. Can you get more details from the device log by running `adb logcat`?